# Only `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle` appears when airplaying on tvOS, despite every other info being in control center

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tvos, airplay

Trying to implement airplay functionality to play audio on Apple TV via airplay, the only info appearing on the tvOS UI is the title, despite every other info is present (and appears in the control center music UI without a problem).

Working with Xcode 10.2.1, app is Objc-Swift5, supporting iOS 10+.

This is the current code:

```c
NSMutableDictionary *audioObjectInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

audioObjectInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = @"Title";
audioObjectInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = @"User";
audioObjectInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = @"Collection";

[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:audioObjectInfo];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `AVMetadataItem`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm using `AVPlayerViewController` and everything shows up as I want if I disable `avplayerController.player?.allowsExternalPlayback = false`, but I don't want to disable that

Comment: @DanielStorm can you provide a bit more info on your comment please

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I forget the specifics, but it involved setting the properties manually. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey